# Encrypted home: if system fails

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, boot-repair

I've been thinking of encrypting my home partition. The only thing that's making me hesitate right now is that there has been situations where my Ubuntu wouldn't boot (power failure that would corrupt something for example). So I'm afraid that, if that's the case, I won't be able to recover my home. Is that how it works or, if I keep the passphrase, it'll all be alright?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been through several power failures and it has never corrupted my encrypted home.

Anyway, taking your situation into consideration, I would say that it is quite safe to encrypt it as long as you keep /home on a different logical partition or disk (as Rinzwind also suggested).

I've even been through a situation when I completely corrupted my Ubuntu installation by doing something stupid but still managed to recover all the data by using the same login password during the new installation (and I did start to backup properly after that heart-in-mouth experience).

And in any case, the pass-phrase will save your life if nothing else works. So write it down somewhere and keep it safe.

So, in a nutshell, as long as you follow some good practices, it should be safe to use encryption.
If you do end up corrupting the partition/disk itself somehow, then it wouldn't really matter anyway if it was encrypted it or not. But other than that, I believe it's fine (from my experience).

Answer (score 3):

If those are concerns...

Put your data on another partition and don't encrypt your home would be my first suggestion. 
That way you'll always have a working system.

Keep your data on the second disk and it will also be easy to move it to another system.

It is also wise to save a none encrypted backup of your data somewhere safe.  In an actual safe. That would prevent loss of data from hardware failure.

Comment: I support this answer. It is *extra important to have good backup routines* with encryption. And you should *test* that you can recover your data from the backup. This is easier, if the data are not encrypted in the backup.

Comment: Those are interesting answers and confirm it was a good thing for me to be careful.  I'll set up a proper backup routine before setting this up. Thanks! :)